# How do I speed up an insert that deals with huge amount of data and non indexed joins?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query that will be used to fetch data from legacy tables. It's no surprise but the amount of data is huge and thus it takes a long time. The first select takes **40 minutes** to run using an empty `dbo.commodities_copy` table as a starting point and yields around **26,000 rows**. Keep in mind that there are separate databases: `STAGING` and `PRESTAGING` and that some joins are made using non-PK fields, which is most definately making an impact in its performance. This is something that I cannot fix, due to the way data was organized from the start. Also the transaction table has around **1 million rows**, which also impacts heavily on performance. The entire script takes a total of 3.5 hours to execute when using an EMPTY `dbo.commodities_copy` table. I have not tested on insertion to a table with data.

The goal of the query is to get *commodity* information from the *transaction* table (if you guessed this was supposed to be noSQL data, you guessed right) and if the *commodity code* exists in the *commodity* table, do not insert a *commodity* in it.

The `group by`s are absolutely needed to get around duplicates, since a transactions may share the same commodity. The commodity code should be unique in the commodities table, but currently it is not - though if it helps, it's possible we could alter it.

What can I do to speed it up?

```
INSERT INTO STAGING.dbo.commodities_copy
(commodity_code,
short_description_sched_b, 
short_description_sched_tsusa, 
long_description_sched_b, 
long_description_sched_tsusa,
measurement_unit_1_sched_b, 
measurement_unit_1_sched_tsusa, 
measurement_unit_2_sched_b, 
measurement_unit_2_sched_tsusa, 
end_use_sched_b, 
end_use_sched_tsusa,
year,
created_by,
created_on,
taxable_sched_b,
taxable_sched_tsusa,
non_taxable_sched_b,
non_taxable_sched_tsusa,
fk_sic_sched_b,
fk_sic_sched_tsusa,
chapter,
header,
sub_header,
needs_validation)
SELECT
    --Distinct
    Commodity_Code,
    iif(miob2.DESC_COMM is null, UPPER(socrata.Commodity_Short_Name), miob2.DESC_COMM) as short_commmodity_description_b,
    iif(mio2tsusa.DESC_COMM is null, UPPER(socrata.Commodity_Short_Name), mio2tsusa.DESC_COMM) as short_commmodity_description_tsusa,
    socrata.Commodity_description as long_commodity_description_b,
    socrata.Commodity_description as long_commodity_description_tsusa,
    iif(miob2.UNIDAD is null, socrata.unit_1, miob2.UNIDAD) as unit_1_b,
    iif(mio2tsusa.UNIDAD is null, socrata.unit_1, mio2tsusa.UNIDAD) as unit_1_tsusa,
    MAX(socrata.unit_2) as unit_2_b,
    MAX(socrata.unit_2) as unit_2_tsusa,        
    socrata.end_use_e as end_use_b,
    socrata.end_use_i as end_use_tsusa,
    MAX(socrata.[year]),
    'system' as created_by,
    getdate() as created_on,
    miob.TRIBUTA as taxable_b,
    miotsusa.TRIBUTA as taxable_tsusa,
    miob.NTRIBUTA as non_taxable_b,
    miotsusa.NTRIBUTA as non_taxable_tsusa,
    sicb.id as sic_id_b,
    sictsusa.id as sic_id_tsusa,
    SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 2) as chapter,
    SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 4) as header,
    SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 6) as sub_header,
    0 as needs_validation

FROM PRE_STAGING.dbo.TRANSACTIONS_FROM_SOCRATA socrata
Left join PRE_STAGING.DBO.MIOB_TBL miob ON miob.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join PRE_STAGING.dbo.MSCHB_TBL miob2 ON miob2.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join PRE_STAGING.dbo.MIOTSUSA_TBL miotsusa ON miotsusa.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join PRE_STAGING.dbo.MTSUSA_TBL mio2tsusa ON mio2tsusa.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join STAGING.dbo.sics_altered sicb ON sicb.sic_code = miob.SIC
Left join STAGING.dbo.sics_altered sictsusa ON sictsusa.sic_code = miotsusa.SIC 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Select Distinct commodity_code from STAGING.dbo.commodities_copy)
group by 
Commodity_Code, 
iif(miob2.DESC_COMM is null, UPPER(socrata.Commodity_Short_Name), miob2.DESC_COMM), 
iif(mio2tsusa.DESC_COMM is null, UPPER(socrata.Commodity_Short_Name), mio2tsusa.DESC_COMM), 
socrata.Commodity_description,
socrata.Commodity_description, 
iif(miob2.UNIDAD is null, socrata.unit_1, miob2.UNIDAD), 
iif(mio2tsusa.UNIDAD is null, socrata.unit_1, mio2tsusa.UNIDAD),
socrata.end_use_e, 
socrata.end_use_i,
miob.TRIBUTA, 
miotsusa.TRIBUTA, 
miob.NTRIBUTA, 
miotsusa.NTRIBUTA, 
sicb.id, 
sictsusa.id, 
SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 2), 
SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 4), 
SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 6)
```

The tables used are the following:

STAGING.dbo.commodities_copy:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[commodities_copy](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [chapter] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [header] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [sub_header] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [commodity_code] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [short_description_sched_b] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [long_description_sched_b] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [measurement_unit_1_sched_b] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [measurement_unit_2_sched_b] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [end_use_sched_b] [int] NULL,
    [sitc_sched_b] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [usda_sched_b] [int] NULL,
    [hitech_sched_b] [int] NULL,
    [naics_fk_id_sched_b] [bigint] NULL,
    [short_description_sched_tsusa] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [long_description_sched_tsusa] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [measurement_unit_1_sched_tsusa] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [measurement_unit_2_sched_tsusa] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [end_use_sched_tsusa] [int] NULL,
    [sitc_sched_tsusa] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [usda_sched_tsusa] [int] NULL,
    [hitech_sched_tsusa] [int] NULL,
    [naics_fk_id_sched_tsusa] [bigint] NULL,
    [year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [created_on] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [created_by] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [updated_on] [datetime] NULL,
    [updated_by] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [needs_validation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [taxable_sched_b] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [non_taxable_sched_b] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [taxable_sched_tsusa] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [non_taxable_sched_tsusa] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [fk_sic_sched_b] [bigint] NULL,
    [fk_sic_sched_tsusa] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

STAGING.dbo.sics_altered:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sics_altered](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sic_code] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [sic_description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [created_on] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [created_by] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The rest are in PRESTAGING:

PRESTAGING.dbo.TRANSACTIONS_FROM_SOCRATA:
This is the table with 1.3 million rows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TRANSACTIONS_FROM_SOCRATA](
    [Trade] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Year] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Month] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Commodity_Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Commodity_Short_Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Commodity_description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cty_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Subcountry_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [district] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dist_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [data] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sitc] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SITC_Short_Desc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [SITC_Long_Desc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [naics] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NAICS_description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [end_use_i] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [end_use_e] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [hts_desc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [unit_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [qty_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [unit_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [qty_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ves_val_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ves_wgt_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [cards_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [air_val_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [air_wgt_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dut_val_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [cal_dut_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [con_cha_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [con_cif_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [gen_val_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [gen_cha_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [gen_cif_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [air_cha_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ves_cha_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [cnt_cha_mo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [rev_data] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

PRESTAGING.dbo.MIOB_TBL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MIOB_TBL](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [COMM] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [INSUMO] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [PBTO] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [SIC] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [NAICS] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [TRIBUTA] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [NTRIBUTA] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [LAST_UPDATE] [date] NULL,
    [LAST_UPDATED_BY] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [CREATION_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [CREATED_BY] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [migrated_on] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

PRESTAGING.dbo.MIOTSUSA_TBL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MIOTSUSA_TBL](
    [COMM] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [INSUMO] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [PBTO] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [SIC] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [NAICS] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [TRIBUTA] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [NTRIBUTA] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [migrated_on] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

PRESTAGING.dbo.MSCHB_TBL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSCHB_TBL](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [COMM] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DESC_COMM] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [UNIDAD] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [LAST_UPDATE] [date] NULL,
    [LAST_UPDATED_BY] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [CREATION_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [CREATED_BY] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [migrated_on] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

PRESTAGING.dbo.MTSUSA_TBL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MTSUSA_TBL](
    [COMM] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DESC_COMM] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [UNIDAD] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [migrated_on] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Let me know if there's anything else I need to provide.

Comment: Without execution plans and table schemas it is hard to comment.  However if the select takes 40 mins on its own then you won't be able to run the entire query any faster than that, without changing approach.  You could maybe speed the insert up by dropped keys from the target table, and then recreating after.

Comment: added table schema and updated time information @destination-data

Comment: some thoughts: see which tables have the highest reads and concentrate there. (right click in query window, Query Options, Advanced, SET STATISTICS IO) You could try to pre-filter some of the tables into temp tables, and try adding indexes to the temp tables on the join fields. Do thorough testing as it may not work. Ensure that all data types on join fields match so SQL Server does not have to do implicit conversions. Ensure that statistics are up to date (exec sp_updatestats). Also grab SQL Sentry Plan Explorer. Gives more information on memory usage and can help find problems with joins.

Comment: Sometimes changin NOT IN to a NOT EXISTS can improve performance. In a query that complicated it mightn't make much difference though

Comment: Can any table be altered or indexes (clustered or non-clustered) be added? Also, the definition of sics_altered is incomplete.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid in my case, NOT IN makes performance worse

Comment: We'll change it not exists then

Comment: @PhilipKelley it should be complete now. It's possible I could alter tables on the STAGING db, but not on the PRESTAGING one.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry, i should fix the query. I meant to say I'm already using `exists` - should be fixed on the question.

Comment: I only see not in in your posted query

Comment: @Jeremy highest cost goes to hash match (aggregate)  when analysing using SentryOne Plan Explorer. It is 54%. Table insert takes 27%. This is I/O + CPU. For I/O alone, 44.8% Hash Match (aggregate) and 48.8% Table Insert....

Comment: what is the timing/IO/Query plan of the procedure if you just select the data without inserting it into the destination?

Comment: If the insert is slow, you can also to try to add the WITH(TABLOCK) hint on the insertion table as long as there are no indexes on the table. Refer to this article for a comprehensive review on bulk loading. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all those left outer joins, the query optimizer has to start with `TRANSACTION_FROM_SOCRATA`, so I would start with that. The only filtering is the NOT IN clause--would that cut down the 1MM rows to something more reasonable? If not, you're pretty much doomed to running at least one table scan (and possibly several) on the entire table.

If filtering on `Commodity_Code` would significantly cut things down, that can only be done if the column is indexed, so that SQL can find and read only those rows. It can only do that if there is an index on column--otherwise you're back to a table scan. Similarly, having an index on `commodity_code` in table commodities_copy` would help as well, if that table is large.

As discussed in the comments, a NOT EXISTS check would be most efficient, written as a correlated subquery:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select commodity_code
                   from STAGING.dbo.commodities_copy
                   where commodity_code = socrtata.Commodity_Code)
```

(I'd want to do a lot of testing on this, checking and double-checking everything. Improving performance is tricky, doubly so when done through SO.)

Comment: I initially pasted the query without the change, but `NOT EXISTS` is already being used and i posted the times using it. I will look into the rest however.

Comment: Will setting commodity_code as unique in the commodities_copy table help? This might be a stupid question but... would i have to do `not exists` comparison when inserting in the table if it becomes unique? It SHOULD be unique but it is currently not. I'm asking because I know that setting as unique adds an index to it. Would this go along with what you're saying?

Comment: Adding the unique constraint should not hurt. The larger the table is, the more likely to help, though it really looks like the pain point is TRANSACTION_FROM_SOCRATA. You don't particularly need `not exists` when populating the table, you just need to make sure the data being loaded is, in fact, unique for that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #socrata(Commodity_Code varchar(100),unit_2_b varchar(50),unit_2_tsusa varchar(50),[year] varchar(50))
insert into #socrata
SELECT
    Commodity_Code,
     MAX(socrata.unit_2) as unit_2_b,
    MAX(socrata.unit_2) as unit_2_tsusa,   
      MAX(socrata.[year]),
FROM PRE_STAGING.dbo.TRANSACTIONS_FROM_SOCRATA socrata
group by Commodity_Code


SELECT
    --Distinct
    Commodity_Code,
    iif(miob2.DESC_COMM is null, UPPER(socrata.Commodity_Short_Name), miob2.DESC_COMM) as short_commmodity_description_b,
    iif(mio2tsusa.DESC_COMM is null, UPPER(socrata.Commodity_Short_Name), mio2tsusa.DESC_COMM) as short_commmodity_description_tsusa,
    socrata.Commodity_description as long_commodity_description_b,
    socrata.Commodity_description as long_commodity_description_tsusa,
    iif(miob2.UNIDAD is null, socrata.unit_1, miob2.UNIDAD) as unit_1_b,
    iif(mio2tsusa.UNIDAD is null, socrata.unit_1, mio2tsusa.UNIDAD) as unit_1_tsusa,
    unit_2_b,
     unit_2_tsusa,        
    socrata.end_use_e as end_use_b,
    socrata.end_use_i as end_use_tsusa,
    [year],
    'system' as created_by,
    getdate() as created_on,
    miob.TRIBUTA as taxable_b,
    miotsusa.TRIBUTA as taxable_tsusa,
    miob.NTRIBUTA as non_taxable_b,
    miotsusa.NTRIBUTA as non_taxable_tsusa,
    sicb.id as sic_id_b,
    sictsusa.id as sic_id_tsusa,
    SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 2) as chapter,
    SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 4) as header,
    SUBSTRING(Commodity_Code, 1, 6) as sub_header,
    0 as needs_validation

FROM #socrata socrata
Left join PRE_STAGING.DBO.MIOB_TBL miob ON miob.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join PRE_STAGING.dbo.MSCHB_TBL miob2 ON miob2.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join PRE_STAGING.dbo.MIOTSUSA_TBL miotsusa ON miotsusa.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join PRE_STAGING.dbo.MTSUSA_TBL mio2tsusa ON mio2tsusa.COMM=socrata.Commodity_Code
Left join STAGING.dbo.sics_altered sicb ON sicb.sic_code = miob.SIC
Left join STAGING.dbo.sics_altered sictsusa ON sictsusa.sic_code = miotsusa.SIC 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Select  commodity_code from STAGING.dbo.commodities_copy where commodity_code = socrtata.Commodity_Code)
```

if `Read uncommitted data` is not a concern then you can use `with (nolock)`

Also your exists clause was wrong and no need of distinct.check rest of the changes.